# Error: Cannot find module '....\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack

I installed Vue.js and ran `npm run serve` which gave me this error:

```
PS C:\Amit\Demo\VUEDemo\myvue> npm run serve

> myvue@0.1.0 serve C:\Amit\Demo\VUEDemo\myvue
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Amit\Demo\VUEDemo\myvue\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js'. Please verify 
that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Amit\Demo\VUEDemo\myvue\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:227:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:364:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:597:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at C:\Amit\Demo\VUEDemo\myvue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\config\base.js:213:26
    at C:\Amit\Demo\VUEDemo\myvue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:268:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Service.resolveChainableWebpackConfig (C:\Amit\Demo\VUEDemo\myvue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:268:26)  
    at Service.resolveWebpackConfig (C:\Amit\Demo\VUEDemo\myvue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:272:48)
    at PluginAPI.resolveWebpackConfig (C:\Amit\Demo\VUEDemo\myvue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\PluginAPI.js:132:25)       
    at serve (C:\Amit\Demo\VUEDemo\myvue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\serve.js:75:31)
    at Service.run (C:\Amit\Demo\VUEDemo\myvue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:262:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5)
    at process.runNextTicks [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/task_queues.js:58:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myvue@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myvue@0.1.0 serve script.   
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\onecenter\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-02T02_14_49_295Z-debug.log
```

The `terser-webpack-plugin` directory looks like this:

[image]

I searched the error on Google but I didn't find a solution

Comment: The plugin directory is missing files, reinstall with `npm clean-install`

Comment: Also add your Webpack configuration.

Answer (score 0):

i was getting the same error for loader in react. Changing my node version to that of the project's fixed it for me.